# Modify datatables update (redraw) request

Tags: datatables

I've copied and slightly changed a pipeline from DataTables website:

```js
DataTable.pipeline = function (opts) {
            // Configuration options
            var conf = Object.assign(
                {
                    pages: 5, // number of pages to cache
                    url: '', // script url
                    data: null, // function or object with parameters to send to the server
                },
                opts
            );
        
            // Private variables for storing the cache
            var cacheLower = -1;
            var cacheUpper = null;
            var cacheLastRequest = null;
            var cacheLastJson = null;
        
            return async function (request, drawCallback, settings) {
                var ajax = false;
                var requestStart = request.start;
                var drawStart = request.start;
                var requestLength = request.length;
                var requestEnd = requestStart + requestLength;
        
                if (settings.clearCache) {
                    // API requested that the cache be cleared
                    ajax = true;
                    settings.clearCache = false;
                }
                else if (
                    cacheLower < 0 ||
                    requestStart < cacheLower ||
                    requestEnd > cacheUpper
                ) {
                    // outside cached data - need to make a request
                    ajax = true;
                }
                else if (
                    JSON.stringify(request.order) !==
                        JSON.stringify(cacheLastRequest.order) ||
                    JSON.stringify(request.columns) !==
                        JSON.stringify(cacheLastRequest.columns) ||
                    JSON.stringify(request.search) !==
                        JSON.stringify(cacheLastRequest.search)
                ) {
                    // properties changed (ordering, columns, searching)
                    ajax = true;
                }
        
                // Store the request for checking next time around
                cacheLastRequest = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(request));
        
                if (ajax) {
                    // Need data from the server
                    if (requestStart < cacheLower) {
                        requestStart = requestStart - requestLength * (conf.pages - 1);
        
                        if (requestStart < 0) {
                            requestStart = 0;
                        }
                    }
        
                    cacheLower = requestStart;
                    cacheUpper = requestStart + requestLength * conf.pages;
        
                    request.start = requestStart;
                    request.length = requestLength * conf.pages;
        
                    // Provide the same `data` options as DataTables.
                    if (typeof conf.data === 'function') {
                        // As a function it is executed with the data object as an arg
                        // for manipulation. If an object is returned, it is used as the
                        // data object to submit
                        var d = conf.data(request);
                        if (d) {
                            Object.assign(request, d);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (conf.data) {
                        // As an object, the data given extends the default
                        Object.assign(request, conf.data);
                    }

                    let response;

                    // Use `fetch` to make Ajax request
                    if (conf.method.toLowerCase() == "get") {
                        console.error("Fetch get");
                        console.log(conf);
                        response = await fetch(
                            conf.url + '?json=' + JSON.stringify(request),
                            {
                                method: conf.method
                            }
                        );
                    } else if (conf.method.toLowerCase() == "post") {
                        console.error("Fetch post");
                        console.log(conf);
                        response = await fetch(
                            conf.url,
                            {
                                method: conf.method,
                                data: request
                            }
                        );
                    }
        
                    let json = await response.json();
                    ajax_always();
        
                    cacheLastJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
        
                    if (cacheLower != drawStart) {
                        json.data.splice(0, drawStart - cacheLower);
                    }
                    if (requestLength >= -1) {
                        json.data.splice(requestLength, json.data.length);
                    }
        
                    drawCallback(json);
                }
                else {
                    json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cacheLastJson));
                    json.draw = request.draw; // Update the echo for each response
                    json.data.splice(0, requestStart - cacheLower);
                    json.data.splice(requestLength, json.data.length);
        
                    drawCallback(json);
                }
            };
        };
        
        DataTable.Api.register('clearPipeline()', function () {
            return this.iterator('table', function (settings) {
                settings.clearCache = true;
            });
        });
```

```js
$(hashtagIdTable).DataTable({
                ajax: DataTable.pipeline({
                    url: "{{ ajaxUrl|raw }}",
                    pages: 5,
                    method: 'POST',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function (d) {
                        return d;
                    },
                    error: datatable_ajax_fail,
                    complete: datatable_ajax_done
                }),
```

This seems to work when loading the page but not when changing page or pagination.

There are a lot of columns so I end up with an error 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

How can I control how the update request is sent??